# Drones photography and ground control regulation

Tags: unmanned-aerial-vehicle, australia

I have been having a conversation at the office about whether to use ground control when using drones/UAVs to capture aerial images. The ground control that I am referring too is any [permanent survey markers](https://www.business.qld.gov.au/industry/titles-property-construction/surveying/permanent-survey-marks), or [Real Time kinematic systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Real_Time_Kinematic) that would aid in improving the spatial accuracy of the data captured. I would imagine that the level of ground control you would use, would depend on the accuracy that you were trying to achieve. I am not sure if this is an aviation question or more GIS related due to using surveying techniques.

Would anyone know if there are any fixed regulation for the use of ground control within Australia?

Comment: Welcome to the site. Could you explain what you mean by *ground control*, and tell us which country is to be considered, as regulation may vary from a country to another.

Comment: @Steve V. All good, I full understand regarding the vote.

Comment: I have read this several times now and the more I read, the more I am convinced that this is not really aviation-related.

Comment: @SentryRaven Yes, it's debatable, although the link about kinematic systems seems to describe something very like [WAAS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wide_Area_Augmentation_System)

Comment: Thinking about what I wrote, I believe that the question is more geared towards GIS and so I'll post on that site. I am happy for this question to be closed.

Comment: I agree to the VTC because it has been answered here: http://gis.stackexchange.com/q/152299/45254